# Borrar localStorage de un iframe incrustado

Tags: javascript, local-storage, iframe

Estoy intentando borrar el localStorage de un `iframe` con el que interactúo con `Window: postMessage()`, pero no logro borrar el localStorage, ¿Conocéis alguna forma de acceder al mismo y borrar ciertas propiedades?

```js
window.addEventListener('message', async function(evt) {
  if (evt&&evt.data.ewkt) {
    window.localStorage.clear();
  } else {
    return;
  }
});
```

Si ejecuto este código, borro el localStorage del navegador pero no el que crea el propio `iframe`.

Comment: El iframe se encuentra en el mismo dominio?

Comment: No, en otro diferente.

Comment: Por temas de seguridad no se puede borrar el LocalStorage de un iframe que se encuentra en otro dominio. Se puede borrar sólo si el iframe se encuentra dentro del mismo dominio o una API te proporciona algún método específico para que puedas borrarlo.